# What is measured by hub size?

Tags: hub

When they say 135mm hub I don't particularly understand. What are you measuring? The radius?

They say that a particular hub will be short for fitting gears. I say if I change rear wheel completely, then is the problem solved?

Comment: Read this page for all you need to know about hub sizing: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width, from locknut to locknut.
[image]

Comment: This is the common convention for expressing hub size. Unfortunately new standards are always being developed that will change this. Pictures of Specialized's 2016 Crux cross bike came out the day before this question was asked showing a 135mm thru axle hub to fit a 130mm road drop out spacing.

Comment: Source? and blah blah blah to meet the length limit